# sed - how to match from string up to fixed position

Tags: regex, sed

Using `sed` ideally and given the input

```
123456789
ABfooEFGH
MNOPfooYZ
```

I want to match the substring beginning with `foo` and ending at position 8 inclusive.

So if I intended to replace that match with `bar`, I want the output

```
123456789
ABbarH
MNOPbarZ
```

I am imagining a `sed` command like

```
sed -E 's/foo.<8>/bar/' input.txt
```

where `.<8>` is imaginary syntax that I made up, meaning "match any character up to fixed position 8 (inclusive)"

---

**That's my question, everything else below is just context to show my reasoning and what I've already tried. Please do answer based on the above alone if you're in a hurry :)**

---

I actually intend to match more stuff after the fixed position too, so more like

```
sed -E 's/foo.<8>[a-z]*/bar/' input.txt
```

although I don't expect that will complicate the answer? So I've left it out of my example.

The match string will actually be a bash variable rather than hard-coded `foo`, so more like

```
str="not foo"
sed -E 's/'"$str"'.<8>[a-z]*/bar/' input.txt
```

The following isn't right

```
str="not foo"
len=${#str}
pos=8
chars=$((pos-len))
sed -E 's/'"$str"'.{'"$chars"'}[a-z]*/bar/' input.txt
```

because I don't know where in each line `$str` will appear - except that I can assume it will always appear before fixed position `$pos`.

Finally, the desired fixed position will also be a bash variable rather than hard-coded, although I don't expect that will complicate the answer?

Comment: Is position 8 the 8th character in string or 8th character after `foo`? or are you looking for a literal `8`? Maybe `foo.*?8`

Comment: `12bar9` in the desired output is confusing.. shouldn't it have 8 characters?

Comment: @user3783243 @Paolo It's the 8th character in the current line, so the match should not be 8 characters long. It's length will vary depending on the position of `foo` within the current line. That's why I can't find an answer to this by googling.

Comment: *It's the 8th character in the current line* what is?

Comment: There is no way to do it with sed or just any single regex. If you know `foo` matches 3 chars, and you want to keep what is before it in positions before Index 5, you can use a fixed solution like `sed -E 's/^foo.{5}/bar/;s/^(.)foo.{4}/\1bar/;s/^(.{2})foo.{3}/\1bar/;s/^(.{3})foo.{2}/\1bar/;s/^(.{4})foo./\1bar/;'` ([demo](https://ideone.com/5RghtL)). It is not possible to generalize here.

Comment: @Paolo When I say I want to match from `foo` up to "position 8", I am referring to the 8th character in the string, not the 8th character after foo. I am not looking for a literal 8

Comment: @benxyzzy, I've taken the liberty of changing your initial example to make it less confusing.

Comment: @Enlico it's a good change, allowed me to remove some of the later clarification

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```bash
sed 's/.\{8\}/&\x0/;s/foo.*\x0/bar/;s/\x0//' input
```

It matches (the first) 8 characters, and appends a `\x0` (null) character after them as a marker. Then replaces from `foo` to that marker inclusive.

If this statement

> I can assume it will always appear before fixed position `$pos`

means that the second `o` of `foo` is not after position 8, then you can shorten to

```bash
sed '/foo/s/.\{8\}/&\x0/;s/foo.*\x0/bar/' input
```

which applies the `s`ubstitution command only on the lines matching `foo`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, thanks, forgot that! That also happens on line containing foo, but in a position that doesn't allow the regex to match.

Comment: From the question: "*because I don't know where in each line $str will appear - except that I can assume it will always appear before fixed position $pos.*"

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, I guess you assume _appear = start & finish_?

Comment: I guess and I hope.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, that allows shortening the solution a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the target ends always before the 8th position, you can play with the pattern space and the hold space:

```
sed '/foo/{h;s/.\{8\}//;x;s/foo.*/bar/;G;s/\n//}' input
```

details:

```
/foo/              # if "foo" exists in the line
{
    h;             # copy the pattern space to the hold space
    s/.\{8\}//;    # remove the first 8 characters (in the pattern space)
    x;             # exchange the pattern space and the hold space
    s/foo.*/bar/;  # replace "foo" until the end of the line with "bar"
    G;             # append the hold space to the pattern space
    s/\n//         # remove the newline (from the pattern space)
}
```

If you have to deal with lines shorter than 8 characters, change `\{8\}` to `\{1,8\}`.

Comment: I like this algorithm.  In perl it's `perl -lpe 'if (/foo/) { $s=$_; $s=~s/.{8}//;  s/foo.*/bar$s/ }' input`  where `$s` is for "suffix".  Neat.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
$ pattern="foo"
$ replacement="bar"
$ awk -v p="$pattern" -v r="$replacement" 'BEGIN{OFS=""} {if (match($0,"foo")) {prefix=substr($0,0,8); suffix=substr($0,9,9); gsub(p".*",r,prefix); print prefix,suffix} else {print}}' file
123456789
ABbarH
MNOPbarZ
```

for strings that include the pattern, it creates two variables - `prefix` and `suffix` - and then removes from the prefix all characters following the pattern if any and replaces them with the replacement, and finally prints both variables.

Answer (score 1):

Perl in stream processing mode allows some arithmetic on the length of the match `/^(.*foo)/` so that you can then adjust the number of characters to match after each foo:

```
perl -pe '/^(.*foo)/; $x=8-length($1); s/foo.{$x}/bar/' file
```